# Twilio "finishOnKey" not working with speech input only

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-node

We have requirement where we ask user for description of issue, it can be long some time. So to gather it we have extended speechTimout to "6" but in some scenario it can be a short so we want to have option where user can press key "1" once he finishes to avoid unnecessary waiting time.

We have provided message to user "Please provide a brief description of your issue. press "1", once you finished"

below is the code

```
this.twilioService.gather(message, {
  ...this.getGatherAttributes(gatherAttrs),
  finishOnKey: '1',
  input: ['speech', 'dtmf'],
  timeout: 3,
  numDigits: 1,
  speechTimeout: 6})
```

but even if user pressed "1" from keypad gather does not stop and call action, instead it wait for long time (6 sec).

Comment: further analysis i noticed if immediately i press finishOnKey without speech input then the finishOnKey works (in twilio logs i can see finishOnKey is set to "1" )

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set `<Gather>` to listen for speech or dtmf input then once one of those inputs starts Twilio will stop listening for the other. So, if you start entering key presses then `finishOnKey` will work. But if you start speaking then `finishOnKey` will no longer work.

The [`speechTimeout` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout) doesn't actually affect how long the caller speaks for, it is a buffer for pauses in speech. If you have `speechTimeout` set to "6" then Twilio will wait for 6 seconds once the caller stops speaking.

You can set `speechTimeout` to "auto", which means that Twilio will stop speech recognition when it detects a pause in speech and return the results.